# Informix with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, informix

How can I set up an application with **Informix** database using **Spring Boot Web MVC** Project.
I have studied the docs on the spring.io website but I couldn't find any anything related to Informix.

Answer (score 2):

Informix has an example github project using Spring boot that hopefully is pretty close to what you would need to know. The important piece is to use maven to get the Informix JDBC driver wired into the Spring application.

https://github.com/informix/informix-db-examples/tree/master/sql/ifx-springboot

Here are the JDBC driver maven coordinates to pull it into your Spring project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.50.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the following steps to connect informix with spring boot

1. In Pom.xml add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.50.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

2. For application configuration you can edit `application.properties` or `application.yml` both do the same magic. In this example i am using `properties.yml`. Add the following configuration to `properties.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <YOUR APPLICATION NAME>
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:informix-sqli://<DATABASE_SERVER_IP>:<DATABASE_SERVER_POST>/<DATABASE_NAME>
   # e.g jdbc:informix-sqli://127.0.0.1:3306/testDB
    username: <DATABASE_USERNAME>
    password: <DATABASE_PASSWORD>
    driver-class-name: com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
  jpa: #to use jpa hibernate with informix
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create #this will create table of your entity on startup
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect
```

Now run your project and it will connect to informix database